# Upload file doesn't work via axios and laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

I tried all previous ways but none helped to me.
I try to upload file via axios:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null)
setFile(event.target.files[0]);     
const uploadFile = () => {
      const formData = new FormData(); 
      formData.append('myFile', file); 
      api.createFile(formData).then(res => {
         console.log(res.data);
      })      
    }

const axios = window.axios
const BASE_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000',
const config = { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}}      
export default {
  createFile: formData =>  
    axios.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/tickets/createFile`, formData, config)
}
```

I already checked the 'file' variable via log and it is exists. But when i get this in laravel:

```
Route::post('/tickets/createFile', function (Request $request){
  return response()->json([
    'file' => $request->file('myFile')
  ]);
});
```

FINALLY: I get empty response which means I can't store it cause I get null value

Comment: you that you need to write upload file code https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: You are not storing the file anywhere on your system ? you just want to file name back or what? If you want to upload it then you need to save it.

Comment: @Ashu I have already tried to store it, but I get error that file is null, since I just check it for a while by sending back via response

Comment: Can you make sure if in dev tools if there's a file named myFile and it's binary? in the request data

Comment: @Ashu I have Form data and MyFile: (binary)

Comment: @Ashu I can't figure out what is going on

Comment: @Ashu Also, when I access to php variable $_FILES I get my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the file in JSON response, but when you access the file using `$request->file('myFile')`, It returns an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`, and when you're returning the json, it's going to return an empty object since `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` is not converted into `json` like models are since it does not have the `toJson()` method on it.

if you dump and die $request->file('myFile')

```
 Route::post('/tickets/createFile', function (Request $request){
     dd($request->file('myFile'));
  });
```

You must be able to see your uploaded file Object. So you can proceed ahead with storing the file using `Storage::put()` method